# Is there a TypeScript equivalent to C#'s attributes

Tags: c#, typescript, custom-attributes

In C# there is a syntax available to define attributes of a property.

```
[Required]
string personName
```

It describes that personName is required. We can get the attributes of a property in any given time via reflection.

I was wondering if TypeScript has some feature like that?

Comment: @wonea What exactly are you looking for here ? basarat's answer  seems clear enough, he was just giving an example of a library, the library code is not magic, you can have a look for inspiration, decorators are TS feature you can read about an implement yourself. Are you looking for a particular example of how to use them ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I was hoping for a more exhaustive answer, including how TypeScript could represent Attributes with a value [MyAttribute("GetThisString")].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, TypeScript has Decorators see in [Official Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, along with the accepted one, because you have linked the official docs, which the accepted answer haven't.

Comment: You can't put a Decorator on an Interface, its members or other compile-time type declarations. So, they're not quite exactly the same. - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6818

Comment: C# Attributes are not executed until you "look" for them via reflections. This is a huge difference.

Answer (score 13):

> I was wondering if TypeScript has some feature like that?

Decorators are like that. E.g. mobx (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) uses it to make things *observable*.

```
class TodoList {
    @observable todos = [];
    @computed get unfinishedTodoCount() {
        return this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.finished).length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You made my day!

Comment: @LukaŠilje keep in mind decorators don't provide type information like .Net Relection API